# i have problem with keras_vggface library

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, deepface

this is my code
`from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace model = VGGFace(model='resnet50')type here`

### and this is the Traceback
``

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10640\2786775362.py in 
----> 1 from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace

ImportError: cannot import name 'layer_utils' from 'keras.utils' (C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils_*init*_.py)
``

i try to update the library to last version
Keras                         2.2.5
keras-vggface                 0.6
keras-utils                   1.0.13
tensorflow                    2.15.0

how can i fix this error :)

That make me use keras_vggface library

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have below version of library , then for `pip install keras_vggface`

```
keras v2.2.4
tensorflow v1.14.0
```

Comment: is still the same error :(